# How to download a file to azure storage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-blob-storage

When i click the download link it send me to a error page trying to debug it its telling me that my given paths format is not supported

In my controller class:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadBlob(string file, string extension)
{
    string downloadPath = await repo.DownloadBlobAsync(file, extension);
    return Json(downloadPath);
}
```

In My Blob Storage class:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadBlobAsync (string file, string fileExtension)
{
    _cloudBlobContainerx = _cloudBlobClientx.GetContainerReference(containerNamex);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _cloudBlobContainerx.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);

    var path = downloadPath + file + "." + fileExtension;
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        fileStream.Position = 1;
        //fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);

        return path;
    }
}
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported

The source of the error :

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
```

below there is the download path value:

```
    public class BlobStorageRepository : IBlobStorageRepository
{
    private StorageCredentials _storageCredentialsx;
    private CloudStorageAccount _cloudStorageAccountx;
    private CloudBlobContainer _cloudBlobContainerx;
    private CloudBlobClient _cloudBlobClientx;

    private string containerNamex = "mycontainer";
    private string downloadPath = @"D:\Images\";

public BlobStorageRepository()
    {
        string accountName = "Account name";
        string keyx = "account key";

            _storageCredentialsx = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyx); //set the azure storage credentals 
        _cloudStorageAccountx = new CloudStorageAccount(_storageCredentialsx, true); //connect to storage service 
        _cloudBlobClientx = _cloudStorageAccountx.CreateCloudBlobClient(); //create the blob service client
        _cloudBlobContainerx = _cloudBlobClientx.GetContainerReference(containerNamex); //contains all blobs for container
```

Comment: If the error is that the path is incorrect, don't you think it's a good idea to show us what the path is, in your question?

Comment: Did you verify that the value for path is valid?

Comment: What is the value of `downloadPath`? What is the value of `file`? What is the value of `fileExtension`?

Comment: @mason  sorry about that ive uploaded above

Comment: Someone please help i've been trying to fix it for ages

Comment: Can you give us an example of the full-path generated by your line: `var path = downloadPath + file + "." + fileExtension;`
And have you tried just writing a blank text file to start with to that final path - check you have access, the path looks ok etc.

Comment: If you're actually running an Azure website I don't think you'll have access to any "D drive", btw ... but I'm guessing somewhat of your environment based on your tags.

Answer (score 1):

> How to download a file to azure storage?

If you want to download the blob file to the client side. You could use the following code to do that.

```
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file + "." + fileExtension);
blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
var contentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType;
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
var response = HttpContext.Response;
response.ContentType = contentType;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + file + "." + fileExtension);
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blockBlob.Properties.Length.ToString());
response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
```